# A couple questions regarding initial ordinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In my course we defined an ordinal to be an initial ordinal if it is infinite and it is not equinumerous to anything less than it. So for example $\omega^+$ is not an initial ordinal because it is equinumerous to $\omega$.

I have a tough time trying to visualise some of these. I know that the 'first one' is $\omega$ and the 'second' one is 'the set of all countable ordinals'. Here are a few confusions that I had:

- Is every initial ordinal a limit ordinal? It is not entirely obvious from its definition but I feel like it should be the case?
- Is it true that every initial ordinal does not possess a largest element? A ordinal $\alpha$ that is said to has a largest element $\beta$, if $\beta\in\alpha$ such that $\forall \gamma \in \alpha,\gamma\leq\beta.$

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Incidentally it's a bad idea to use "$\omega^+$" to denote the ordinal successor of $\omega$: the $+$-superscript almost universally denotes the *cardinal* successor, so e.g. $\omega^+=\omega_1$. Instead, the right notation for the ordinal successor of $\omega$ is just $\omega+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **not** the case that every limit ordinal is an initial ordinal, and it **is** the case that every initial ordinal is a limit ordinal. There is a single intuitive picture which helps in both cases: [Hilbert's hotel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel).

Hilbert's hotel (forgetting the "room/guest" language and just talking about sets of natural numbers) includes two specific cases:

- There is a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and  $\mathbb{N}\cup\{*\}$: just send $*$ to $0$ and $n$ to $n+1$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. (To me $0$ is a natural number.) This generalizes to a proof that **no infinite initial ordinal is a successor ordinal**: given an infinite successor ordinal $\alpha+1$, simply "move the last element to the beginning." You can check that the result, if we define things properly, is $\alpha$.
- There is a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}\times\{1,2\}$: just "put $\mathbb{N}\times \{1\}$ on the evens" and "put $\mathbb{N}\times \{2\}$ on the odds." This can be recast as a proof that **the limit ordinal $\omega+\omega$ is not an initial ordinal**: basically, for $n$ finite send $n$ to $2n$ and $\omega+n$ to $2n+1$.

---

I think it will also help to focus on the "gap" between $\omega$ (= the first infinite initial ordinal) and $\omega_1$ (= the first uncountable initial ordinal, or the first initial ordinal $>\omega$). Basically, it's important to grasp just how rich the interval $[\omega,\omega_1)$ is in the ordinals. A good example to consider is the ordinal [$\epsilon_0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_numbers_(mathematics)), which may feel gigantic at first - but is still countable, and so is incredibly, impossibly, indescribably **tiny** compared to $\omega_1$.

(Note that there's an annoying notational overload around $\epsilon_0$ and its relatives: we have to distinguish between *ordinal* exponentiation and *cardinal* exponentiation. In cardinal exponentiation $2^\omega$ is already uncountable, but it is ordinal exponentiation which is used in the definition of $\epsilon_0$.)